# Will "x == (x/10)*10;" be optimised away

Tags: java

Context : We have business requirement that a value is reported at 3 or 4 digit string. If the string is 3 digits, it's value is actually *10.

e.g. 123 represents 1230, where as 4567 represents 4567.

When converting back from a stored integer to the string, the above code is seen as one way to determine this. The question we have is would the optimizer remove this code for x (integer and float). Specifically looking at Java, but the follow on question is how would other languages behave

The obvious other way to do this is use Mod (x%10).

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: It better shouldn't. There are enough values for which the check returns false.

Comment: what if later your string becomes 5 digits? will you also check `x == (x/100)*100`?

Comment: Are there situations where you can legitimately get a 4 digit string ending in 0?  If so, you may need some extra metadata for a backwards conversion.

Comment: @Eric: That provides an answer for one compiler on one JVM. Trying is not a valid way to ensure certainty

Comment: @Daniel: Agree 100%, however my question is not what it should or shouldn't do, but what does it do?

Comment: @Luiggi: The Business requirements is what they is. I did not write them, and am not qualified to second guess them.

Comment: Well, if it is correct, it leaves it, if it's incorrect, who knows?

Comment: @Thomas : The requirements are such that a 4 digit string with a 0 last character is invalid (Other wise I would just print 4 digits).

Comment: @mattnz business requirements can (and will) change over time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question makes a false presumption that `(x/10)*10` necessarily equals `x`.  In general, Java compilers and virtual machines are allowed to optimize anything any way they want to so long as they satisfy the requirements of the Java Language Specification.

If `x` is a `float` or a `double` then `x == (x/10)*10` if there is no floating point rounding error.  However, 10 is an `int` and if `x` is an `int` or `long` then the expression uses Integer division.  The Java Language Specification is crystal clear on what the [division operator](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/andru/javaspec/15.doc.html#5047) does with respect to integers.  Namely it rounds toward zero.  So the Java compiler may optimize that expression to something other than a divide followed by a multiply, but whatever the optimizer does, it has to produce the correct result.

Comment: Your first paragraph about a false presumption is wrong. The code example tests to see if x is the same as (x/10)*10.

Comment: @mattnz and by asking if the test can "be optimized away" the question is presuming that the test always yields the same result.

Answer (score 2):

> the follow on question is how would other languages behave?

Did some quick tests in C with gcc at various optimization levels and looked at the code generated. No, it doesn't get optimized away. Even when the compiler can evaluate `x == (x/10)*10` at compile time (because  *x* is a constant) then it is still evaluated correctly.

Update: this is an obvious result if you think about it. A compiler shouldn't be  able to 'optimize' `(x/10)*10` to just `x` for an integer `x`, because it'll only work for a 1/10th of the set of integers.

Answer (score 0):

> the above code is seen as one way to determine this

I don't know why, because it doesn't. All it does is change the last digit to zero if it wasn't already zero.

The compiler & JVM aren't permitted to optimize it away because that wouldn't give the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the requirements. You could certainly do something like

`String s = x < 1000 ? String.valueOf(10*x) : String.valueOf(x);`

The optimizer can not possibly remove the code you have because with integer division it isn't an identity, but it seems like a very complicated approach.

Incidentally, if your values are sure to top out at 9999, and speed is important, have a static array of 10,000 Strings created either by a static initializer or lazily.

Answer (score -1):

As has been explained this cannot be optimized away but why would you not use

```
(x%10 == 0) ? x/10 : x
```

to convert back?

Comment: -1: Does not answer the question, and "The obvious other way to do this is use Mod (x%10)."

Comment: @mattnz thank you for the downvote. The point I was trying to make is that mod is the *better* way to do it